# Getting the download count of a specific S3 object

Tags: logging, amazon-s3, cdn

I've got a number of S3 objects that are available to my customers. Since I'd like to bill my customers by usage, I wondered if there is any smart kind of way to get the number of times a given file has been downloaded?

Alternatively, I suppose I could parse the log files provided by S3, but with 10m+ fetches per customer this might be bit of a task.

Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you let them download via HTTP then you could use a URL shortener service to redirect to your file (like goo.gl). I suppose they can handle load and they also provide some nice stats next to total clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect through a script on your site that increments a count before redirecting to the S3 URL.

Comment: That wouldn't be an option since the reason I'm using S3 is to avoid passing stuff through my server.

Comment: Well, if it's a header-based redirect, your server won't actually be serving the data of content... but since you mention 10m+ fetches, I'm guessing you might also want to avoid the request load in the first place, which is understandable.

Comment: Indeed. The average file size is ~10kb.

Comment: Parsing the log files is probably the most straightforward way then.

Answer (score 0):

There'd be some assembly required and it needs some cleanup, but [I wrote an app](https://github.com/ingenthr/changedetector) for this based on node.js and [Couchbase](http://couchbase.com).  I need to update it a bit more, but it will count HTTP 200s based on object size rather than just hitcount alone (which is inaccurate) and I've just been updating it to aggregate HTTP 206s.