# Count of JS S3 Object Access

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my app, my customers can create small widgets with text fields and text. They can customize the look and feel through JS and CSS. I upload the JS and CSS in my S3 bucket and use Cloudfront for CDN.

Once the widget is created, they can embed the widget on their website using embed code.

In the embed code, I have used a 1x1 pixel image which is used to send request to php so I can increase the visit counter.

```
public function track(Request $request) {
    // increase stored number here

    header('Content-Type: image/gif');
    return base64_decode('R0lGODlhAQABAJAAAP8AAAAAACH5BAUQAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICBAEAOw==');
}
```

My server is getting overload because of the visit counter. I want to now track the number of visits to embedded widgets for each customer by using S3 and Cloudfront access count.

I searched and found - [Getting the download count of a specific S3 object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028103/getting-the-download-count-of-a-specific-s3-object), but it is for download.

How can I get the count of times when S3 object is accessed?

Comment: "accessed" and "downloaded" mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: why don't you use the same methodology but on a different server e.g. google analytics has counter for image downloads. and include that transparent image in your widget. hint: try file random versioning to avoid browser caching which prevents the loading hence not counting the next access.

Answer (score 0):

Use cloudtrail to and parse the logs.  [List of actions trackable by cloudtrail on s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL shortener service to redirect to your file (like goo.gl, bit.ly), they will track number of clicks,views etc, and it wont even overload your server.

Hope it helps.